# iOS Dropbox Core API or Sync API

Tags: ios, dropbox, core-api

My app needs to save and retrieve images from root dropbox folder (not my app's root folder under dropbox), currently I setup my app in App Console with files and detesters, need access to files already on Dropbox and specific file types for images.

Which type of dropbox api should I use ? Core API or Sync API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to retrieve files from Dropbox then you need to use Core API of Dropbox.
For better use you need to read

```
 https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios
```

this.
This is a good way to retrieve specific files from Dropbox in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the right way. It seems that Sync API can only work under the app's folder.

Comment: The question mentions both the Core and Sync API options, but orthogonal to this is that there are also different "permissions" offered by the Dropbox API. The Sync API doesn't currently support the full Dropbox permission, but it does support both the app folder and file type permission. You can find more information on the different permissions here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions

Comment: You can also check this link for dropbox integration and accessing files : http://innofied.com/integration-of-dropbox-in-ios-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is [deprecating Sync API](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/)